# loading camera from device connected to computer is slow in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am getting the following warning:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of IOKit.framework/IOKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
```

Why is this and how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error says that you are missing the `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework` framework.  Have you installed other copies of xcode/developer tools?  If so you may need to copy over the Device Support for this version.

---

**Option 1**

This framework is usually available in `/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework` (if its not there use this command to find it: `find /System -type d -name "IOKit.framework"` or `find /Developer -type d -name "IOKit.framework"`) so you can copy it to where your xcode is looking for by opening up `Terminal.app` and type this:

```
[ 16:01 root@MacBookPro / ]# sudo cp -rv /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework"
```

If that fails because there is no `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)` directory, then what you can do is this:

```
[ 16:01 root@MacBookPro / ]# mkdir -p "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/"
```

Then:

```
[ 16:01 root@MacBookPro / ]# sudo cp -rv /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework"
```

---

**Option 2**

Download xcode/developer tools again, install it to something besides `/Developer`, such as `/Developer-4.2`, then copy the directory `/Developer-4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)` to `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)`

---

**Option 3**

Look in the `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` directory and there might be other versions but not `4.3.5 (8L1)`.  If there is a `4.3.5` but no `4.3.5 (8L1)` then what you can do is make a symlink between the two with the following command in Term:

```
[ 16:01 root@MacBookPro / ]# cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/
[ 16:01 root@MacBookPro / ]# ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 "4.3.5 (8L1)"
```

---

Or, just uninstall xcode by running the `/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools` command, then download and re-install.

Comment: I checked and there is actually an IOKit.framework... I tried doing option 3 and there seems to be 4.3.5 (8L1) but not 4.3.5